# meteorjs scss @import chain

Tags: meteor, sass

I'm writing a package with meteorjs and I use fourseven:scss and materializecss (scss version);
the folder structure of styles folder is the following:

```
|-- main.scss
|-- materialize
    |-- materialize.scss
    |-- components
    |   |-- prefixer.scss
    |   |-- (all others materialize css' components)
    |-- myPlugin
        |-- myPlugin.scss
```

main.scss uses

```
@import "materialize/materialize";
@import "myPlugin/myPlugin";
```

and myPlugin.scss uses

```
@import "../materialize/materialize";
```

but the app crashes on startup saying that components/prefixer file is not found (the source of error is the file myPlugin/myPlugin.scss);

If I put all css files in the same folder, I can get everything work but I'd like to keep things structured; does someone have some suggestions about how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with certain versions of that plugin if you follow this discussion it will lend some insight: https://github.com/meteoric/ionic-sass/issues/16

Try setting specific version of the package... 
meteor add fourseven:scss@=3.2.0

And/Or, a fix I've been using for ages it seems is to comment out the problem includes until first build, and afterwords you can uncomment it and the build should work.